# How to emit state always with @ngrx store.select?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I took the following code from the [@ngrx example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/find-book-page.ts).

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.searchQuery$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchQuery).take(1);
    this.books$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchResults);
    this.loading$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchLoading);
  }
```

In the above code, the `store.select` will emit values only if the new results are different from the previous.

How can I emit `this.books$` always irrespective of the new stream is same or different from the previous stream? Which `store` method I have to use for that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the rxjs-operator `map` - it works slightly different from `select` though:

```
store.map(state => state.someAttribute.someSub);
```

---

While it is correct, that `select` will only emit data when the *selected item* changed - the question is: Why do you need the update? If there is no change in the data there should be no need to update the view.

Comment: I have a case where the UI asks for data from ```@ngrx DB``` (```cache```) through ```@ngrx effect```. If there is no data in the ```cache```, I send an action, and in the reducer which checks for the payload in this action finds nothing and then sets a state property called ```cacheAvailbility``` to ```false```. That state is subscribed by a container ```observer``` initiates another action to read from the DB. So the state this ```observer``` has subscribed can be ```false``` last time, and ```false``` again if no data in the ```cache```. In both these situations, a DB ready is necessary.

Comment: I used a ```state``` to manage the cache availability which might have made this complicated. I can dispatch another action in the effect itself, but then I have to use a ```if``` statement like ```if (data === undefined) {
 store.dispatch(new ReadFromDBAction(customerId))
} else {
 store.dispatch(new ReachFromCacheSuccessfulAction(customerId))
}```

Comment: Sounds to me like some complicated architecture, that I'm pretty sure can be simplified - but that's probably part of a different question - just one thing: do not use `dispatch` within an effect - an effect should only return subsequent actions - dispatching an action in the middle of an effect __will__ lead to complications in the ngrx-store

Comment: I have another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597070/how-to-remove-the-control-statements-from-ngrx-effects) if you would like to answer that one.